# Why doesn't this searchbox work?

Tags: xhtml

```
  <!--got this from http://www.getgooglesearch.com/-->
  <fieldset id="searchbox">  
    <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
      <input type="text"   name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" />
      <input type="image" src="../media/google.gif" alt="Submit button" title="Submit" /><br />
      <input type="checkbox"  name="sitesearch" value="arenanewbs.com" checked="checked" />Only search Areneanewbs.com<br />
    </form>
  </fieldset>
```

If you uncheck the box the google site search works, but on my actual site it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the name should be site instead of sitesearch

Comment: I tried that, it says Your search - information searched - did not match any documents.

Comment: When I tried Site instead of site search it searches google.com only.

Answer (score 0):

It " *does not work* ", because the **search returns no results on the page you provided**. The `arenanewbs.com` domain you provided [does not even exist](http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=arenanewbs.com&type=domain).

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDjap/) for a proof, that **the searches for different pages actually work** (in my example this is bbc.co.uk and " *wall street* " phrase).

Answer (score -2):

make `value="http://www.google.com"` and it will work.